reledmac: familiar notes in a RTL edition as a clean paragraph without footnote separators and with flexible spacing
I am working on a Hebrew edition with LuaTeX that includes both critical and familiar notes. My challenge is with the formatting of the familiar notes.
The familiar notes mainly consist of short references, like this: אב׳ ג ד. Since I have a large number of these, I want them to appear as a single paragraph rather than individual footnotes. However, the familiar notes are not formatted as a clean paragraph. Lines that begin with a new footnote are indented, which breaks the visual flow. I believe this issue is related to the footnote separator and the spacing between the footnotes, which are controlled by the parameters \parafootsepX and \afternoteX. Setting these parameters to \hspace{0em} and 0em, respectively, produces the desired paragraph format, but without any spacing between the individual footnotes. Defining flexible spacing between footnotes does not resolve the indentation issue. Even when I try to right-align the paragraph with a ragged edge, the lines starting with new footnotes remain indented.
So, my question is:
How can I organize familiar notes in a Hebrew edition using reledmac as a clean paragraph without a footnote separator and with flexible spacing between the footnotes?
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac} % Load Reledmac for critical editions
\usepackage{fontspec} % Support for custom fonts (necessary for Hebrew)

% Babel for multilingual support
\usepackage[bidi=basic,english]{babel} % 'bidi=basic' is crucial for LuaLaTeX
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew} % Set Hebrew as the main language
\babelfont{rm}{SBLHebrew} % Set font for Hebrew text

% Reledmac settings
\Xarrangement{paragraph} % Footnotes are arranged in a paragraph
\arrangementX{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ $\parallel$\hspace{0.5em}} % Separator between footnotes
\Xafternote{0.5em} % Space after footnotes
\Xbeforelemmaseparator{0em} % Space before lemma separator
\Xafterlemmaseparator{0.5em} % Space after lemma separator
\Xlemmaseparator{]} % Separator for lemma content

\fnpos{critical-familiar} % Positioning of critical footnotes

\lineation{page} % Line numbering per page


\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}

Thank you in advance for your help!

There is (at least) a mistake in your code. \babelfont[rm]{hebrew}{SBLHebrew} should be \babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{SBLHebrew} or even just \babelfont{rm}{SBLHebrew}, because Hebrew is the main language.

Thank you very much for pointing this out. I have adjusted the code.

Once the font is correctly setup, the \hebrewfont’s are redundant, at least in this example.

I’m investigating the indent issue, but reledmac is a very complex package, so it might take me some time.

Thank you so much. I have updated the code once more. It should now be free of redundancies.

Unfortunatly, I guess that, even in LTR mode, it is not possible to have a flexible space between paragraphed footnote, due to the way paragraphed footnote are conceived.

As to the wrong indents, there is a bug in the babel bidi algorithm, because it inserts a ‘direction change’ between a penalty and a space. This means the latter is not discarded at the beginning of a line. Here is quick workaround.
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac} % Load Reledmac for critical editions
\usepackage{fontspec} % Support for custom fonts (necessary for Hebrew)

% Babel for multilingual support
\usepackage[bidi=basic,english]{babel} % 'bidi=basic' is crucial for LuaLaTeX
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew} % Set Hebrew as the main language
\babelfont{rm}{SBLHebrew} % Set font for Hebrew text

% Reledmac settings
\Xarrangement{paragraph} % Footnotes are arranged in a paragraph
\arrangementX{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ $\parallel$\hspace{0.5em}} % Separator between footnotes
\Xafternote{0.5em} % Space after footnotes
\Xbeforelemmaseparator{0em} % Space before lemma separator
\Xafterlemmaseparator{0.5em} % Space after lemma separator
\Xlemmaseparator{]} % Separator for lemma content

\fnpos{critical-familiar} % Positioning of critical footnotes

\lineation{page} % Line numbering per page

% ======= Workaround =========
\directlua{

function fix_penalty_dir (head)
  local prev_penalty
  for item in node.traverse(head) do
    if item.id == node.id'penalty' and not prev_penalty then
      prev_penalty = item
    elseif item.id == node.id'penalty' then
      % pass
    elseif prev_penalty 
        and item.id == node.id'dir'
        and item.dir:sub(1,1) == '-' then
      node.insert_before(head, prev_penalty, node.copy(item))
      node.remove(head, item)
    else
      prev_penalty = nil
    end
  end
  return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "pre_linebreak_filter", fix_penalty_dir, "fix_penalty_dir")
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "hpack_filter", fix_penalty_dir, "fix_penalty_dir")
  
}
% ==========================


\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
לורם איפסום דולור
סיט\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר
סוברט\footnoteA{~ע״פ אב׳ ג ד.}
לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם
סולגק.\footnoteA{~אב׳ ג ד.}
בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש.
\edtext{תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם}{\lemma{תרבנך \dots סתשם}\Afootnote{סתשם תרבנך וסתעד לכנו}}
השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}



Thank you so much for promptly resolving the issue!
